# Any (easy) way to make an IHP app into a library?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I am developing some things in one IHP project, is there any way to easily package that as a library and import that into another IHP project? I'd rather keep them separate and be able to develop the main project separately. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate? What kind of things? An IHP project mostly consists of Haskell code, and of course you could always move Haskell code into a library. Extracting routes and models is a bit trickier.